# PortNotOpenError while connecting to Modbus

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi4, modbus, modbus-tcp

I am trying to connect to Modbus TCP using the modbus-serial library for JavaScript. I have confirmed that I am using the correct IP address and port. My network doesn't have a firewall and if it does, using 2 other alternatives, I was able to connect my Modbus to the devices and make other devices do many things. However, I am still getting this error:

PortNotOpenError {
name: 'PortNotOpenError',
message: 'Port Not Open',
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED'
}

Here's my code:

```
const ModbusRTU = require("modbus-serial");
console.log("Imported Library");

const client = new ModbusRTU();
console.log("Defined Client");

client.connectTCP("", { port: });
console.log("Connected to Modbus TCP server");

console.log("");

client.writeCoil(2000, 0x01, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Coil successfully set!");
  }
});
```

I have removed the IP and port in this question.

I expected the code to turn on the A.C. in my hall, but it showed the error.

Also, the first app was too expensive so I couldn't use it and the second app was free, but it's graphics couldn't be customised and I had to resort to my current option, NodeJS (v20.10.0) and some addons to customise the view.

Also, I tried using both 2000 and 2001. I don't know the offset of this library (How to check it) ?

https://github.com/yaacov/node-modbus-serial/issues/115 - In this, they're using RS485. I'm using TCP IP.

Could this be due to me using Replit temporarily? Am I supposed to use another library of JS (Which library, how to use it?) ? Is my code incorrect (I found the code from the [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modbus-serial) and editted it) ?

Comment: Please confirm how you are running the app (if it's running on replit servers then it's not going to be able to access things on your local network). Whilst I understand why you are hiding IP addresses this does make it harder to respond (please confirm if the device is on a LAN or has a public IP address).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The Modbus device is on LAN.

Comment: And where are you running the code? (you mention Replit in your question, one of it's features is to run code on a cloud server, which would not be able to access something on your LAN).